# Append text to JTextField

Tags: java, string, jtextfield

I have a JTextField, and I am trying to append some string to it. The way I am trying to do this is to set the text to whatever it already is plus what I wish to append.

```
GUI.sumField.setText(GUI.sumField + Double.toString(GUI.tempNum1));
```

This sets the text to some apparently random number, not what is expected.

Comment: I believe it should be ```GUI.sumField.setText(GUI.sumField.getText() + Double.toString(GUI.tempNum1));```

Comment: So, all your fields are still static? Why do you ask questions if you don't listen to answers?

Comment: @Cygwinnian: you should make that an answer.

Comment: Also note that with string you concanete values with +.. not arithmethic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, judging from this:

> in short, when i set a JTextField to what it is, + a preset double, it reads as some weird text.

You are obviously setting the text wrong.

Try this:

`GUI.sumField.setText(GUI.sumField.getText() + Double.toString(GUI.tempNum1));`

This actually gets the `sumfield`'s text and concatenates it to the double, and then sets `sumfield` with that text.